# Why HBase Java Client is slow compared to REST/Thrift

Tags: rest, hbase, thrift

I am running some performance tests on HBase Java client / Thrift / REST interface.
I have a table called “Airline” which has 500K rows. 
I am fetching all 500K rows from the table through 4 different Java programs. (using JAVA Client, Thrift, Thrift2 and REST)

Following are the performance numbers with various fetch sizes. 
For all these the batch size is set to 100000

---

```
[Table which shows the performance numbers. All times are in ms][1]
```

[Perf Numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owk0x.png)

---

I could see that, there is a performance improvement as we increase the fetch size in case of REST, Thrift, and Thrift2.

But with Java API, I am seeing consistent performance, irrespective of fetch size. 
Why fetch size is not impacting in JAVA Client?

Here is snippet of my Java Program

---

```
Table table = conn.getTable(TableName.valueOf("Airline"));
Scan scan =  new Scan();
ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);

for (Result[] result = scanner.next(fetchSize); result.length != 0; result = scanner.next(fetchSize))
```

{
       - process the rows
    }

---

Can someone help me in this. Am I using wrong methods/classes for data fetching through JAVA client.

Comment: There is too little information in your question to be making a guess at what might be the reason for difference. What is the HBase version you are using? Do you use the default config or you have a custom config? Do you set any "caching" for the scanner?

Answer (score 1):

Your scanner is not set up right to fetch the number of rows you want in a timely manner. In other words, you're tuning the ResultScanner, not the thing actually doing the scan, the Scan object.

I believe the functions you want are *partially* the following:

```
scan.setCaching
scan.setCacheBlocks
```

https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html

You would call those functions before your loop...

**Source**
Pig's HBaseStorage#initScan function

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  scan.setMaxResultSize() is defaults to 2MB, I changed to 10 MB then it gave good performance.  I could see there is 100% improvement.  But for different values of scan.setBatch() I am not seeing any difference in the performance.

Comment: Okay. Traditionally what you would do is answer your own question and accept your answer since that's what worked for you. If you don't mind doing that, please, it would clear this question from the "unanswered questions" queue. Or I can add `setMaxResultSize` to my answer and you can accept that. Whatever works best for you. Let me know...